# Setting google map current location in circular view

Tags: android

I am new to android.I would like to know how to put a google map current location in circle[I want to know how to set google map current location inside the circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s3PS.png)

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029529/draw-circle-of-certain-radius-on-map-view-in-android

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a UI with an opening in which your google map is behind, you can create a circle with a transparent interior. You can get more information on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098538/transparent-circle-with-border).

Note, however, that if your circle is not located at the center of the screen, you will need to find the offsets and move the camera to the respective location given these offsets.